# Remove characters from regex query

Tags: regex

I have trouble understanding why my regex query takes one extra character besides the symbols I have told regex to include into the query, so this is my regex:

```
([\-:, ]{1,})[^0-9]
```

This is my test text:

```
Test- Product-: 1 --- 3 hour  ,--kayak:--rental
```

It always includes the first character of each starting word, like P on Product or h on hour, how can I prevent regex from including those first characters?

I am trying to get all dashes, double points, comma and spaces excluding numbers or any characters.

Comment: Maybe `[-:, ]+(?!\d)`? Or `[-:, ]+(?![-:, \d])`? Could you please explain what you are after.

Comment: or perhaps `([\-:, ]{0,})(?<=[^0-9])` ?

Comment: `P` is not a digit, so `[^0-9]` will match it. If you don't want that, don't put `[^0-9]` in your regex.

Comment: Ah sorry of course ... I have not mentioned what I am after ... very sorry :/ I am trying to get all dashes, double points, comma and spaces excluding numbers or any characters

Comment: Ok, so use `[-:, ]+`. It does not match digits nor letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, this worked, that is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^0-9]` part of your regex matches any char but a digit, so you should remove it from your pattern.

There is no need to wrap the character class with a capturing group, and `{0,1}` is equal to `+`, so the whole regex can be shortened to

```
[-:, ]+
```

Note that `-` in the initial and end positions inside a character class does not have to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)